# Is there a specific way to give a certain subclass some functions of the superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, polymorphism

## The Problem

I'm trying to create an application where an object class can implement some  
operations from the total pool of available operations. The end goal is to not have any code duplication and to abide by the laws of OOP as much as possible.

In more detail, I'm trying to make a search engine using Lucene. Lucene
uses many indices. I've already implemented a simple structure where different index-objects inherit the methods of a parent class. The problem is that, whatever method is implemented in that parent class, it automatically becomes available for all subclasses to use. I want to give the option to the user to determine if he wants to do a phrase search, a term search or whatever else there is available for **that** specific index. The catch is, some indices shouldn't have the option to conduct phrase search, for example.

## First Thoughts

I've thought of implementing something close to the *Composite* pattern,
as described by the GoF. I would implement the search operations (e.g. term search, phrase search) as primitive operations implementing some *Component* class and add these primitive objects later on to a *Composite* object. The *Composite* object will be implementing the same *Component* class as the primitives.

```java
public abstract class Index {
    public Index(String indexPath) {
        // Constructor using the information provided by the subclass
    }

    public void phraseSearch(...) {
         // Do the operation
    }

    public void termSearch(...) {
        // Do the operation
    }

    public void categorySearch(...) {
        // Do the operation
    }
}

public class ReviewIndex extends Index {
    public ReviewIndex() {
        super("./review_index/");
    }
}

public class TipIndex extends Index {
    public TipIndex() {
        super("./tip_index/");
    }
}
```

## Expected Outcome

The class `ReviewIndex` shouldn't be able to perform a categorySearch but be
able to execute phraseSearch and termSearch. Respectively, the `TipIndex` class
should be able to execute some of the parent class methods.

## Final Thoughts

I know that in my solution there is no code duplication but there  
are useless methods being generated each time a new index object is created.  
Thank you all in advance!

P.S. If you think the *Composite* pattern is the way to go, in which way would you actually add the primitive objects to the composite class and in which way would you invoke them when need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods defined in a superclass are available at deriving classes but with Java 8 you might be able to get something like this by using default-methods in interfaces. So instead of one abstract class containing all possible methods you might implement four interfaces

```
public interface Searchable {
    public String getIndexPath();
}

public interface PhraseSearchable extends Searchable {
    public default void phraseSearch() {
        String indexPath = getIndexPath();
        // do the search
    }
}

public interface TermSearchable extends Searchable {
    public default void termSearch() {
        String indexPath = getIndexPath();
        // do the search
    }
}

public interface CategorySearchable extends Searchable {
    public default void categorySearch() {
        String indexPath = getIndexPath();
        // do the search
    }
}
```

To avoid duplicate code you can create an abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractSearchable implements Searchable {
    private String indexPath;

    public AbstractSearchable(String indexPath) {
        this.indexPath = indexPath;
    }

    // other methods that might be useful
}
```

Your actual classes can then implement the corresponding interfaces

```
public class ReviewIndex extends AbstractSearchable implements CategorySearchable {
    public ReviewIndex() {
        super("./review_index/");
    }
}
public class TipIndex extends AbstractSearchable implements PhraseSearchable, TermSearchable {
    public ReviewIndex() {
        super("./review_index/");
    }
}
```

If this is possible depends heavily on the actual implementation of the search methods. Interfaces can't contain any members, etc. so these methods must be able to run for themselves (like a static method without using any static members of the class). You might to overcome this problem by adding more methods to the `Searchable` interface that provide the data and do the implementation in the abstract class but that might expose internal stuff to the public because all the declared methods in an interface are public.

Comment: This will work nicely for my problem. Adding individually each operation that i want onto the `Index` (or your `AbstractSearchable`) class is what i was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `categorySearch(...)` for `ReviewIndex` class then create one more hierarchy where you keep the `categorySearch(...)` method.

**Example:**

```
public abstract class Index {
    public Index(String indexPath) {
        // Constructor using the information provided by the subclass
    }

    public void phraseSearch(...) {
         // Do the operation
    }
}

// Give a meaningful Name
public abstract class IndexChild1 extends Index {
    public void categorySearch(...) {
        // Do the operation
    }
}

// Give a meaningful Name 
public abstract class IndexChild2 extends Index {
     public void termSearch(...) {
            // Do the operation
     }
}

public class ReviewIndex extends IndexChild1 {
    public ReviewIndex() {
        super("./review_index/");
    }
}

public class TipIndex extends IndexChild2 {
    public TipIndex() {
        super("./review_index/");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a viable solution but i believe @Lothar 's answer is more elegant as to my application. I think this would lead to the creation of way too many subclasses that each `extend` a specific operation. Maybe aggregation would be the solution to **that** problem but i think interfaces is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Composite pattern if you need to have the same objects and use them as you wish in your ReviewIndex and TipIndex classes. you can use a list which implies aggregation and you can use one instantiation of each object(PhraseSeach, TermSearch, CategorySearch) in any order you want. 
here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.run();


    }

    public void run() {
        ReviewIndex ri = new ReviewIndex();
    }


    public interface ISearch {
        public void search();
    }

    public class SearchComposite implements ISearch{

        private List<ISearch> l = new ArrayList<ISearch>();

        public SearchComposite(String index) {
            System.out.println(index);
        }

        public int addSearch(ISearch search) {
            l.add(search);
            return this.l.size() - 1;
        }

        public List<ISearch> getSearch(){
            return this.l;
        }

        public void search() {
            System.out.println("search");
        }
    }

    public class CategorySearch implements ISearch{
        @Override
        public void search() {
            System.out.println("category search");
        }
    }

    public class PhraseSearch implements ISearch{
        @Override
        public void search() {
            System.out.println("phrase search");
        }
    }

    public class TermSearch implements ISearch{
        @Override
        public void search() {
            System.out.println("term search");
        }
    }



    CategorySearch cs = new CategorySearch();
    TermSearch ts = new TermSearch();
    PhraseSearch ps = new PhraseSearch();


    public class ReviewIndex {
        SearchComposite sc = new SearchComposite("./review_index/");
        public ReviewIndex() {
            int p = sc.addSearch(ps);
            int t = sc.addSearch(ts);
            sc.search();
            List<ISearch> s = sc.getSearch();
            s.get(p).search();
            s.get(t).search();
        }
    }

    public class TipIndex {

        SearchComposite sc = new SearchComposite("./tip_index/");
        public TipIndex() {
            int p = sc.addSearch(ps);
            int t = sc.addSearch(ts);
            int c = sc.addSearch(cs);
            sc.search();
            List<ISearch> s = sc.getSearch();
            s.get(p).search();
            s.get(t).search();
            s.get(c).search();
        }
    }
}
```

the output of the code above is:

```
./review_index/
search
phrase search
term search
```

and we have used the same CategorySearch, TermSearch and PhraseSearch for ReviewIndex and TipIndex classes.

Comment: If i'm undestanding your answer correctly, every time i would do a `search()` on the `ReviewIndex` i'd end up calling all the decorated functions which is something i'm aiming to avoid. I want to individually call, say `phraseSearch()` on the `ReviewIndex`, get the results, print them to the user, and later on do a new/clean `termSearch()` on the same object.

Comment: You are correct. I have changed the code and used composite pattern which suits better with your need.